# fstab parse error when adding mhddfs entry

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

Having zero luck getting mhddfs to boot automatically. Also tried the rc.local addition to no avail. Here is my fstab. Let me know if there's anything else I can do to help figure this out.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=dd3d249f-6912-4979-88c0-ee02c72c1875 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=44B0-FDB4  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=e6b9121b-a133-4222-a547-65c3fb652d2b none            swap    sw              0       0
mhddfs#/media/andrew/WD60EZRZ,/media/andrew/8TB,"/media/andrew/Seagate Expansion Drive" /Storage fuse allow_other,nofail,defaults 0 0
```

How can I add my `mhddfs`?

Comment: Better start with your goal and also describe what you did.

Comment: You should probably escape the `#`, which I guess would be a comment character.

Comment: Sorry I'm reasonably new to Linux so are you referring to the hash after mhddfs in the last line?

Comment: Yes. The `#` in `mhddfs#/media...`

Comment: @MichaelBay, I have completely started from scratch on 16.04 for a HTPC build. I had mhddfs working on the prior build. If i issue this command 


(sudo mhddfs /media/andrew/WD60EZRZ,/media/andrew/8TB,"/media/andrew/Seagate Expansion Drive" /Storage -o allow_other -o nonempty) to manually mount the 3 drives in /Storage it works great.


But the comparable fstab entry gives this error (mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 14.)




Thanks for all the replies so far!

Comment: @muru removed that # to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely sure what i did but here is the fstab that made everything work!

```
UUID=dd3d249f-6912-4979-88c0-ee02c72c1875 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

UUID=44B0-FDB4  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation

UUID=e6b9121b-a133-4222-a547-65c3fb652d2b none            swap    sw             0       0
LABEL=8TB /mnt/8TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
LABEL=5TB /mnt/5TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
LABEL=6TB /mnt/6TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
mhddfs#/mnt/6TB,/mnt/8TB,/mnt/5TB /Storage fuse allow_other,nofail,default_permissions,nonempty 0 0
```

It seems the 3 drives i was attempting to mhddfs together werent mounting on boot. In Disks I removed the auto mount and changed them to Mount By Label for easier identification. I suspect the quotations around the Seagate drive may have caused issues but Im not sure. Hope this helps someone!